# How to run micrometer elastic with micrometer spring legacy?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, micrometer

im quite new to spring and am trying to connect my application to an elk.
The Application is running spring boot 1.5.5, hence I'm using micrometer legacy.
My pom looks like this:

```html
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-spring-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-elastic</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Whenever I'm trying to start my app I recieve following error:

```
    2020-06-19 13:38:29 [ WARN] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded containe
r; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat > [main] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEm
beddedWebApplicationContext
 2020-06-19 13:38:39 [ INFO]

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. > [main] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReport
LoggingInitializer
 2020-06-19 13:38:39 [ERROR] Application startup failed > [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
 org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to
start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.FatJarRouter.main(FatJarRouter.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:595)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:138)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [io/micrometer/spring/autoconfigure/web/serv
let/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMetricsFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyExc
eption: Error creating bean with name 'elasticMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [io/micrometer/spring/autoconfigure/export/elastic/ElasticMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied
dependency expressed through method 'elasticMeterRegistry' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticConfig' define
d in class path resource [io/micrometer/spring/autoconfigure/export/elastic/ElasticMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang
.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.export.elastic.ElasticPropertiesConfigAdapter] for persistence metadata: could not find class that it depends
 on
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:234)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:182)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:177)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:159)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:241)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:228)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [io/micrometer/spring/autoconfigure/expo
rt/elastic/ElasticMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticMeterRegistry' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCr
eationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticConfig' defined in class path resource [io/micrometer/spring/autoconfigure/export/elastic/ElasticMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-proce
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1643)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findConcreteMethodsOnInterfaces(ReflectionUtils.java:635)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:614)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:431)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
        ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.validate.Validated
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
        ... 63 common frames omitted
```

The root cause seems to be the class io.micrometer.core.instrument.config.validate.Validated which seems not to be present in the package as it should be.
Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

the root case was a mismatch of the versions o micrometer core which was pulled by other dependencies.
I imported the following

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-spring-legacy</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-elastic</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And run into the error above because both dependencies contain a version of micrometer core. In my case version 1.3.9. The needed class was added to micrometer.core with release 1.5.x
So the solution was to define that dependency explicit with version 1.5.x

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-spring-legacy</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-elastic</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/micrometer-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Anyway the application does not start due to socket timeouts but te error above is fixed. :D
Migration to spring boot 2 might be a faster solution. xD